# EF Code First Migrations Strange Behaviour

Tags: entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have this scenario. I implemented Code First Migrations on a project in this way

1. I set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true and created my database.
2. 2 fellow developers got my code and it all works fine for them.
3. I later modified my model and set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to false and used Add-Migration, Update-Database to apply this change.
4. These same fellow developers took an update of the code and it all works fine for them.
5. A third developer got the latest code (for the first time) and the database was created for him correctly (with the changes in step 3) and everything worked fine ... until ... check this out ... he added the attribute OutputCache to an action method in a controller. He never changed the model. He never did anything else, he just added that attribute. When he did that, he got this error.

> 'Unable to update database to match the current model because there
>   are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write
>   the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable
>   automatic migration. Set
>   DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable
>   automatic migration.'.

He made no database changes. He made no model changes. He just added this attribute. Now, when he removed this attribute it still gives the same error.

We have tried everything.

a) deleted the database

b) set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true

c) ran Update-Database

d) ran Add-Migration, Update-Database

Nothing is working. He still has this error with or without his OutputCache change (which I think has nothing to do with it).

Is there something wrong with my use of AutomaticMigrationsEnabled or the steps that I followed? Should AutomaticMigrationsEnabled not change during the lifetime of an application?

Frustrated and confused.

Sachin

Comment: Do all of the machines have the same bitness?

Comment: What do you mean by bitness?  Do you mean are they all 64bit etc - if so then yes they are all 64bit.

Comment: Have you ruled out something wrong on his machine? What happens if another developer gets a fresh clone of the code and tries this?

Comment: Well @Haacked it now is not only his machine but the machine of all developers, including me, for which reason I have reverted to using DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges.